# Why does loading dataset from Cassandra fail with NullPointerException?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I am trying to read/write to Cassandra from Spark and using these dependencies:

```
"com.datastax.spark" % "spark-cassandra-connector-unshaded_2.11" % "2.0.0-M3",
"com.datastax.cassandra" % "cassandra-driver-core" % "3.0.0"
```

And this is the code :

```
import com.datastax.spark.connector._
val sparkConf: SparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName(appName)
      .set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", hostname)
      .set("spark.cassandra.auth.username",user)
      .set("spark.cassandra.auth.password",password)

 val spark = SparkSession.builder().config(sparkConf).getOrCreate()
val df = spark
      .read
      .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
      .options(Map( "table" -> s"$TABLE", "keyspace" -> s"$KEYSPACE"))
      .load() // This Dataset will use a spark.cassandra.input.size of 128
```

However on trying to spark-submit, I am getting this on the df ...load() line above

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster$Manager.close(Cluster.java:1516)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster$Manager.access$200(Cluster.java:1237)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.closeAsync(Cluster.java:540)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.close(Cluster.java:551)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$.com$datastax$spark$connector$cql$CassandraConnector$$createSession(CassandraConnector.scala:162)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$$anonfun$3.apply(CassandraConnector.scala:149)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$$anonfun$3.apply(CassandraConnector.scala:149)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.RefCountedCache.createNewValueAndKeys(RefCountedCache.scala:31)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.RefCountedCache.acquire(RefCountedCache.scala:56)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector.openSession(CassandraConnector.scala:82)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector.withSessionDo(CassandraConnector.scala:110)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.partitioner.dht.TokenFactory$.forSystemLocalPartitioner(TokenFactory.scala:98)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra.CassandraSourceRelation$.apply(CassandraSourceRelation.scala:255)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra.DefaultSource.createRelation(DefaultSource.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:345)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:149)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:122)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

M3 is a milestone release and you should really use the real release 2.0.2 which is currently the latest.

https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector#most-recent-release-scala-docs

You should *not* be including the java driver in the same project with the Cassandra Connector. Unless you are explicitly re-shading inside your project and that is for experts only. See the [FAQ](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/FAQ.md#how-do-i-use-libraries-which-depend-on-the-cassandra-java-driver) for more details.

I would recommend using only the shaded artifact and following the examples as posted [here](https://github.com/datastax/SparkBuildExamples/tree/master/scala/sbt/oss)

```
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkVersion % "provided",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % sparkVersion % "provided",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-hive" % sparkVersion % "provided",
  "com.datastax.spark" %% "spark-cassandra-connector" % connectorVersion % "provided"
```

And launching uses Spark Packages or an assembly

//Assembly

https://github.com/datastax/SparkBuildExamples#sbt

// Packages

https://spark-packages.org/package/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! The links helped. I removed the driver. I am doing this now (other than the spark-core, etc):
//sbt 
`"com.datastax.spark" %% "spark-cassandra-connector" % "2.0.2" % "provided",`
//code
`val df = spark.read.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra").options(Map( "table" -> s"$TABLE", "keyspace" -> s"$KEYSPACE")).load()`

and my jar is a fat jar with all dependencies. I am doing a spark-submit. And yet I see the same NPE again.

Comment: The examples in SparkBuildExamples say this : "Note that spark-cassandra-connector should be provided with '--packages' flag to spark-submit command". Do I need to do that even for spark-submit? I thought that would be needed for doing in spark-shell only. Can that cause the error? If yes, what should my spark-submit look like?

Comment: I took the example from the SparkBuildExamples link and I am trying the WriteRead one as it is. The original NPE is gone and I am getting this now :`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$.apply(Lorg/apache/spark/SparkContext;)Lcom/datastax/spark/connector/cql/CassandraConnector;`  Any suggestions? I am using the spark-core, spark-sql and Cassandra-connector jars as above (no hive, does that matter?)

Comment: You have to either use --packages or --jars and provide details about the 3rd party plugins such as Cassandra connectors. It will be good, if you paste spark-submit command in the question, if it is failing.

Comment: @RussS  Thanks a lot for your help. I was able to resolve this issue with the pointers you provided!

Comment: @DurgaViswanathGadiraju Thanks! I got a cue from your comment and as it happens, my `sbt sync` command never synced the jars properly in my cluster. So even though I had changed dependencies in my build.sbt but the changed jars were not reflected in my lib/* folder which had the old jars as well and hence the conflict